# Graph axes not showing correctly in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a 2x2 graphs in python and is struggling with the axes. This is what I get so far - the axes on each subplot is messed up.

[image]

This is my code:

```
def plotCarBar(df):
    fig = plt.figure()
    j = 1
    for i in pandaDF.columns[15:18]:
        cat_count = df.groupby(i)[i].count().sort_values().plot(figsize= 12,12), kind = 'line')
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, j)
        j += 1
    return ax.plot(lw = 1.3)

plotCarBar(pandaDF)
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need two loops. If you post some sample data, we may be able to make better sense of what your `cat_count` line is doing. As it stands, I'm not sure if you need two counters (`i` and `j`).

Generally, I would also recommend using `matplotlib` directly, unless you're really just doing some quick and dirty plotting in pandas.

So, something like this might work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

randoms = np.random.rand(10, 4) # generate some data
print(randoms)

fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(1, randoms.shape[1] + 1): # number of cols
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i)
    ax.plot(randoms[i, :])
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
[[0.78436298 0.85009767 0.28524816 0.28137471]
 [0.58936976 0.00614068 0.25312449 0.58549765]
 [0.24216048 0.13100618 0.76956316 0.66210005]
 [0.95156085 0.86171181 0.40940887 0.47077143]
 [0.91523306 0.33833055 0.74360696 0.2322519 ]
 [0.68563804 0.69825892 0.5836696  0.97711073]
 [0.62709986 0.44308186 0.24582971 0.97697002]
 [0.04356271 0.01488111 0.73322443 0.04890864]
 [0.9090653  0.25895051 0.73163902 0.83620635]
 [0.51622846 0.6735348  0.20570992 0.13803589]]
```

[image: matplotlib plot]